# If P then not Q and if not P then Q. What is the relationship called?

Tags: logic

Is there a name of this relationship? 
P => Q and ~P => ~Q seems to be called equivalence. But could not find a name for P => ~Q and ~P => Q by cursory googling and browsing related Wikipedia articles.

Comment: More than incompatible, $P$ and $Q$ are *negations* of one another.

Comment: @hardmath not really, it's rather "$P$ is equivalent to $\lnot Q$" (not $P=\lnot Q$). Mutually exclusive may work, although incompatible has a nicer ring.

Comment: @ClementC.:  I'm arguing this is a stronger relationship than mutual exclusiveness.  Whether one wants $P$ is *equivalent* to the negation of $Q$ instead of $P$ *is* the negation of $Q$ seems too fine of a point to argue in a Comment.

Comment: Well, we are literally asked about semantics here, so I'd argue it does matter :) Discarding the fact that it's equivalent to the negation, not the negation itself, would amount to saying that "equivalence" is "equality."

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't think incompatible is quite right? For example, having 4 legs is incompatible with being fish, but not having 4 lags does not imply being fish.

Comment: @user69715: You are right, poor choice. Deleting.

Answer (score 2):

$(P\to Q) \wedge (\neg P\to \neg Q)$ is an *equivalence* between $P$ and $Q$.

$$\begin{align}(P\to Q) \wedge (\neg P\to \neg Q) \quad\iff&\quad P\leftrightarrow Q\\[1ex]\iff&\quad (P\wedge Q)\vee(\neg P\wedge \neg Q)\\[1ex]\iff&\quad (P\vee\neg Q)\wedge(\neg P\vee Q)\end{align}$$

$(P\to \neg Q)\wedge(\neg P\to Q)$ is an *exclusive disjunction* between $P$ and $Q$.

$$\begin{align}(P\to \neg Q)\wedge(\neg P\to Q) \quad\iff&\quad P\oplus Q\\[1ex]\iff&\quad (P\vee Q)\wedge(\neg P\vee\neg Q)\\[1ex]\iff&\quad (P\wedge\neg Q)\vee(\neg P\wedge Q)\\[1ex]\iff&\quad P\leftrightarrow \neg Q\end{align}$$